# Aiogram. Как сделать так, что бы если сообщение равнялось хотя бы одному элементу из списка, то чето запускалось

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Мне нужно, что бы селектор запускалался, если я отправляю в бота одно из этих сообщений.
по итогу приходится вставлять этот кусок кода, который внутри функции selector, в остальные функции, а это очень некрасиво

```
funcs = ['','','','']
@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: (sexy(msg)),state='*')
async def selector(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == "":
        await state.finish()
        await message.answer("===== CINEMA MENU =====", reply_markup=cinema_keyboard)
        await UserState.cinema.set()
    elif message.text == "":
        await state.finish()
        await message.answer("===== POWER MENU =====", reply_markup=power_keyboard)
        await UserState.power.set()
    elif message.text == "":
        await state.finish()
        await message.answer("===== MEDIA MENU =====", reply_markup=media_keyboard)
        await UserState.media.set()
    elif message.text == "":
        await state.finish()
        await message.answer("===== VOLUME MENU =====", reply_markup=volume_keyboard)
        await UserState.volume.set()

def sexy(msg):
    if msg.text in funcs:
        return True
    else: return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос понял верно, то можно использовать декоратор @dp.message_handler для каждой функции меню, которая будет вызываться при нажатии соответствующей кнопки

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text == "", state='*')
async def cinema_menu(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("===== CINEMA MENU =====", reply_markup=cinema_keyboard)
    await UserState.cinema.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text == "", state='*')
async def power_menu(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("===== POWER MENU =====", reply_markup=power_keyboard)
    await UserState.power.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text == "", state='*')
async def media_menu(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("===== MEDIA MENU =====", reply_markup=media_keyboard)
    await UserState.media.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text == "", state='*')
async def volume_menu(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("===== VOLUME MENU =====", reply_markup=volume_keyboard)
    await UserState.volume.set()
```

Comment: спасибо большое. не знаю, как сам до этого не додумался, теперь даже стыдно как-то) ахах